# Running a command completely indepenently from script

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have recently come across some situations where I want to start a command completely independently, and in a different process then the script, equivalent typing it into a terminal, or more specifically writing the command into a .sh or .desktop and double clicking it. The request I have are:

- I can close the python window without closing the application.
- The python window does not display the stdout from the application (you don't want random text appearing in a CLI), nor do I need it!.

Things I have tried:

- os.system waits.
- subprocess.call waits.
- subprocess.Popen starts a subprocess (duh) closing the parent process thus quits the application

And thats basically all you can find on the web!
if it really comes down to it I could launch a .sh (or .bat for windows), but that feels like a cheap hack and not the way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to place an & after the command when called from os.system, would that not work?     For example:

```
import os
os.system( "google-chrome & disown " )
```

Comment: If python exits, the child process might be quit too.  Adding a `nohup` might do it, though.

Comment: Add `nohup` or just add `disown` after `&`.

Comment: how is this for crossplatformness?

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
import os
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as f:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=f, stderr=f)
```

Comment: thanks for reading my op. :) this spawns a child process, not a full process

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your question. Can you give an example when this does not satisfy your requirements?

Comment: This opens a child process. If the parent process exits with code 0 it is fine, but when I kill it in another way, like closing the terminal, it quits the child process too

Comment: That's odd. If I use `command = 'ls -lRa / > /tmp/out'`, I can run the script, close the terminal, open a new terminal and `ps axu | grep ls` shows `ls -lRa` is still running.

Answer (score 0):

Spawn a child process "the UNIX way" with fork and exec. Here's a simple example of a shell in Python.

```
import os

prompt = '$ '
while True:
    cmds = input(prompt).split()
    if len(cmds):
        if (os.fork() == 0):
            # Child process
            os.execv(cmds[0], cmds)
        else:
            # Parent process
            # (Hint: You don't have to wait, you can just exit here.)
            os.wait()
```

Comment: This seems a bit complicated if I still have to do something else for windows but ill try it

Comment: This works well, I just changed the os.execv(cmds[0], cmds) line to os.system(cmds) and removed the .split(). Sadly, since all of these don't work for windows "command & disown" is easier.