# using call() to execute cat, with pipes and redirected output in python

Tags: python, shell

I've this shell command:

```
cat input | python 1.py > outfile
```

`input` is a text file with values

```
3
1
4
5
```

and `1.py` is:

```
t = int(raw_input())

while t:
    n = int(raw_input())
    print n
    t -= 1
```

It runs perfectly when I enter it in the terminal.

However, when I run this from Python using this code:

```
from subprocess import call
script = "cat input | python 1.py > outfile".split()
call(script)
```

I get:

```
3
1
4
5

cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: python: No such file or directory
t = int(raw_input())

while t:
    n = int(raw_input())
    print n
    t -= 1
cat: >: No such file or directory
cat: outfile: No such file or directory

cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: python: No such file or directory
cat: >: No such file or directory
cat: outfile: No such file or directory
```

How do I get it right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the arguments to `call` are executed directly, not passed to a shell, so the pipelines and IO redirections are not processed. Use `shell=True` and a single string argument instead.

```
from subprocess import call
script = "cat input | python 1.py > outfile"
call(script, shell=True)
```

However, it's better to let Python handle the redirections itself without involving the shell. (Note that `cat` here is unnecessary; you could use `python 1.py < input > outfile` instead.)

```
from subprocess import call
script="python 1.py".split()
with open("input", "r") as input:
    with open("outfile", "w") as output:
        call(script, stdin=input, stdout=output)
```

Comment: what if I have parantheses in my command like below: 'cat <(cat bal_fold_2.csv) <(tail -n+2 bal_fold_3.csv)  > bal_train.csv'

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in a shell where `|` and `>` are considered as special redirection symbols, Python's `call()` sees them as normal and are passed as well as normal arguments to `cat`.  You may consider calling a command via a shell with other methods like `os.system`:

```
import os
os.system("cat input | python 1.py > outfile")
```

Answer forwarded from [Running a command completely indepenently from script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806892/running-a-command-completely-indepenently-from-script).

Comment: The Python documentation itself prefers the `subprocess` module to using `os.system`.